# what is the correct way to dispatch an action in angular?

Tags: angular, ngrx, effects, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

could you please tell me what is the correct way to dispatch an action.

In the component, we do like that using `store` using `store.dispatch` than action.

```
onLoginButtonClick(user: Authenticate) {
    this.store.dispatch(new Authctions.Login(user));
  }
```

Now using `ngEffect` we dispatch action without using `store` only use `new Action name` why ?

```
export class AuthEffect {
  @Effect()
  login$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionsTypes.LOGIN),
    map((action: Login) => action.payload),
    switchMap((auth: Authenticate) => {
      return this.authService.login(auth).pipe(
        map(user => new LoginSuccess({user})),
        catchError(error => of(new LoginFailure(error)))
      );
    })
  );
```

why it is used like this

```
 new LoginSuccess({user})
```

can we used like this `this.store.dispatch( new LoginSuccess({user}))` ? in effect ?

any update?

Answer (score 6):

Effects return Actions, like the documentation [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md) states.

Ngrx will internally dispatch the action returned from your effect.

You could directly use `this.store.dispatch( new LoginSuccess({user}))` in an effect, **but you shouldn't as it is not needed and will only clutter your code**!

If you need to dispatch multiple actions from your effect you can do something like this:

```
@Effect() save = this.update$.pipe(
   map(action => action.payload),
   switchMap(payload => this.myService.save(payload)),
   switchMap(res => [
       new NotificationAction('save success'),
       new SaveSuccessAction(res)
   ])
);
```